# Can I "convert" a Ubuntu installation to an elementary installation?

Tags: ppa, ubuntu

If I'm running a version of Ubuntu more recent than that on which elementary OS is based, can I install elementary's components onto it for a working elementary OS setup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could install the elementary desktop and all the standard applications on top of your existing Unity desktop with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

You'll probably have to logout and switch to Pantheon in your display manager.

Comment: I believe there are two elementary PPAs, not one. If using 14.04, then the second PPA upgrades the necessary Libraries. If using 15.04, then there may be some incompatibilities.

Comment: Are you referring to [versable](https://launchpad.net/~versable/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-update)?

Comment: No, I think there are two official PPAs enabled when you install elementary.

Comment: If the PPA issue is cleared up, I'll accept this as the answer. I currently use Ubuntu 15.04 (with only minor issues), and switch between Pantheon and KDE 5.

Comment: Ah, the other one is the OS Patches PPA. I'll edit this answer now.

Comment: I would specify that this is not a recommended method. Although you certainly can end up with a working system, it can harldy provide the "real elementary experience" the devs have designed. I think there are many more tweaks under the hood which cannot be reproduced just by adding a couple of PPAs.

Comment: @saintjules on SE "I think" is not quite enough ;)

Comment: It might be worth adding that adding PPAs does not change your settings and won't remove stuff that's already installed. It also won't perform any other tasks that our build system does that isn't provided in packaging. You won't get the exact same experience as a clean install of elementary OS. You'll have a Pantheon on Ubuntu experience.