# Can I upgrade the elementary's ubuntu base to Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: release-loki, ubuntu

Can I upgrade the elementary's ubuntu base to Ubuntu 16.10??
Will it be safe to do???

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need Ubuntu 16.10? There may well be a workaround which doesn't require upgrading the underlying Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: Yes you can. No you shouldn't.**

Actually this is not exactly the same as "converting an Ubuntu installation to elementary OS" which results in a kind of Pantheon Desktop Environment-on-Ubuntu, the result of upgrading would be something like that as well.

Cf. [Can I "convert" a Ubuntu installation to an elementary installation?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/241/can-i-convert-a-ubuntu-installation-to-an-elementary-installation)

*So even if globally this kind of upgrade should be "safe", some bugs and glitches are likely to appear, so I would advise against it.*